# Dell Dock USB ports not working

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a Dell Latitude E5570 running Windows 7. There are three USB ports on the laptop (one on the right hand side and two on the back) and when I connect my keyboard and mouse to them they work fine.

However, when I attach the laptop to the Dell Dock (I think its the Dell Advanced E-Port 2) is when I get problems with the USB ports. The USB port on the side of the laptop works fine. The two on the back of the laptop stop working. None of the USB ports on the Dell Dock work.

I have two monitors attached to the dock and they work fine.

Odd thing is that they seem to work when the system is first powered up as the laptop is protected by some sort of device encryption (???) and I can type the password fine. I'm assuming this is a Windows issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this my mouse and keyboard were plugged into the USB ports on the back of the dell dock (I used the laptops keyboard and touchpad to navigate).

First of all I found that Windows hadn't been updated in a while so I got all the updates. I'm not sure if this actually solved anything but is worth doing anyway.

```
Start > Control Panel > Windows Update
```

Once all updates had been installed I restarted my laptop. I then opened device manager

```
Start > Control Panel > Device Manager
```

In the `Universal Serial Bus controllers` section I could see the following entries

[image]

When I unplugged my mouse the device manager refreshed and one of the `USB Composite Device` entries disappeared. I then noticed that in the `Other Devices` section that there were several `Unknown Device`s with yellow warning triangles. I right clicked on one of the entries and selected `Update Driver Software`.

For whatever reason this worked! My mouse and keyboard are working through the dock.

Comment: Well `Drivers` are the first place to check for these type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a TB16 Dell Dock just now after some Windows Updates installed Dell drivers and firmware. Windows seems to be vague on the details. We are on a delayed WSUS, so not sure when these were released, if at all, officially.

```
Dell - Extension - 1.0.0.14
Dell - Extension - 1.3.2.178
Dell, Inc. - Firmware - 1.8.1
```

None of either the 3 USB 3.0 and 2 USB 2.0 ports worked. Display output wasn't affected.

The solution was to reinstall the [Dell Thunderbolt Controller](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=tbt79) -- despite Dell's website telling me it was not meant for my service tag. Note that this is different than the Thunderbolt Driver. And the version linked will eventually be out of date.